# How can I click button and change style in scss?

Tags: html, sass, onclick, css-selectors

I have scss file where on click of `Filter button` I want to display   buttons(Present in `demos class`). As of now I am able to achieve this using `:active` selector. But for this selector to work I have to longpress the button for sometime. I am trying to achieve this just on click of the button. How can I achieve such functionality (Without Jquery or JS)?

Here is my scss file

```
.bot {
  &:active {
     .demos {
      .tools {
        background-color: pink;
        display: block;

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my html file

```
<button class="bot" (click)="xy()">Filter
    </button>
    <div class="demos">
      <div class="tools">
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using :target?

Comment: I tried, that wont work

Comment: Your `scss` file is invalid because you try to target an element that has the class `.demos` that is wrapped in an element that has the class `.bot`. But when you look at your `html` file the `div` with the class `.demos` is not in the `button` with the class `.bot`

Comment: Then how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can either style a checkbox to look like a button and use the :checked selector...

Or, if it's enough to show them once you clicked the button and there is no need to hide the content again, you can use an a-tag as an anchor link to the div you want to show and display it by selecting it with the :target selector:

```css
.demos {
  display: none;
}

.demos:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#demos">Filter</a>
<div class="demos" id="demos">
  <div class="tools">
    content ...
  </div>
</div>
```